# PHP Neo4j NOT relationship query is not working

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute the `NOT relation` query but the condition just does not apply. What am I doing wrong here?

The query I tried:

```
MATCH (blog:Blog), (user:User{id:3})-[:FOLLOWS]->(otherUser:User) 
WHERE NOT ((otherUser)-[:OWNS]->(blog))
RETURN blog
```

Query should return - all blogs that my friends do not own. My id is 3.
So all the blogs owned by other users should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You span up a cross product between all blogs and all friends of the user.

But the condition is only checked for each pair.

You probably want this:

```
MATCH (user:User{id:3})
MATCH (blog:Blog)
WHERE NOT ((user)-[:FOLLOWS]->()-[:OWNS]->(blog))
RETURN blog
```

or this

```
MATCH (user:User{id:3})-[:FOLLOWS]->(otherUser:User) 
WITH collect(otherUser) as friends
MATCH (otherUser)-[:OWNS]->(blog:Blog)
WHERE NOT otherUser IN friends
RETURN blog
```

Comment: The first query itself solved my problem. Thank you very much.